# JQuery append() in Rails view gives "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to dynamically add/remove select boxes to my form on the click of a button

Here is my `options/new.html.erb`:

```
<br>
  <h3>Add Options</h3>
  <div class="input_options_wrap">
    <button class="add_options_button">+</button>
    <%=select_tag "options[]", options_for_select(@options.pluck(:option)), class: "form-control", prompt: "Select Option" %>
  </div>
```

This shows one line with the select box and the options. I want the user to be able to select as many options as he wants to add, but they need to be from this list of options only. So, there is the add_button and here is the script to handle the add/remove select boxes on click:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_options_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_options_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initial text box count
    $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><%=select_tag "options[]", options_for_select(@options.pluck(:option)), class: "form-control", prompt: "Select Option" %><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })
  })
</script>
```

Now here is the problem. On rendering this html page, I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`. Here is how the above code (relevant line) is being parsed:

```
$(wrapper).append('<div><select class="form-control" id="options_" name="options[]"><option value="">Select Option</option><option value="book">book</option>
<option value="copy">copy</option></select>
</div>');
```

I believe this exception is because inside `append`, it expects one string of "html code" while here because of random line breaks, that single string is no more syntactically correct. Is there any way around this?

Comment: You have to escape or remove line breaks in javascript strings

Comment: @charlietfl and how do we do that? This is kind of internal "rendering" by rails, that expands select_tag like this.

Comment: See this line in main code body: `<%=select_tag "options[]", options_for_select(@options.pluck(:option)), class: "form-control", prompt: "Select Option" %>` which is expanded in html form as `selects and options` (Refer last block I've posted).

Comment: I think you should use the remote: true with AJAX in rails. It will make easy for you.

Comment: @Bharatsoni I don't understand...how do I use ajax here anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put that html into a script tag to use as template and retrieve it as html from that template. By setting the `type` to something other than javascript the browser won't compile it as script and the html inside won't be turned into dom nodes either.

```
<script type="text/template" id="select-template">
  <div><%=select_tag ..... %><a..></div>
</script>
```

Then change:

```
$(wrapper).append('html string')
```

To:

```
$(wrapper).append($('#select-template').html());
```

Comment: Can you enlighten me a little as to what was the problem earlier and why does this work?

Comment: I don't know rails but that method seems to put line breaks in the output and line breaks in  javascript strings need to be escaped. Passing return of a function is different